# Can not access javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting an array in an API response. I have logged the response and checked in the browser console. Before expanding the log it can be seen that there are two items in data. But when I expand, it can't be seen. I took the data into different variable but the same is happening there also.
[image]

Comment: It must be mutated after it has been logged out. Try logging a snapshot of that object after getting the response: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)))`

Comment: We need to see your code! Chances are that you're logging it before the response has actually returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are logging an object then what gets logged on the console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time.

Create a deep copy of the data that you want to log.

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourResponse)))
```

Read about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log_static#parameters)